# Provisioning Profiles Stopped Working (Free Apple Account)

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile, provisioning, ios-provisioning

I've been able to develop apps perfectly fine until today when the *Fix Issue* button stopped working. Now I'm greeted with the error:

> Creating a profile requires having a device registered in the Member Center.

I'm using a free account so, as far as I know, I can't register a device in the Member Center. There doesn't seem to be any way for me add a profile in XCode either.

As depicted in the attached screenshot, the buttons for Mac development and iOS development don't even exist. All of my old projects work perfectly fine. Is this a bug or have I just forgotten something

[image: View Details Window of Apple ID in XCode Accounts Tab]

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. Hopefully this will help someone else in the future. If provisioning profiles start failing without warning or explanation, reselect a target device from the Set Active Scheme dropdown item in the toolbar to the right of the play and stop buttons.